# How can I use Key-Value Observing with Smart KeyPaths in Swift 4?

Tags: swift, key-value-observing, swift4

Could you help me how to manage to be notified when the contents of `NSArrayController` are modified, using **Smart KeyPaths**?

Inspired by

**Key-Value Observing**:
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/AdoptingCocoaDesignPatterns.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH7-ID12

**Smart KeyPaths: Better Key-Value Coding for Swift**:
https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0161-key-paths.md

I mimicked the example code of the article.

```
class myArrayController: NSArrayController {
  required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: coder)

    observe(\.content, options: [.new]) { object, change in
      print("Observed a change to \(object.content.debugDescription)")
    }
  }
}
```

However, that is not working. Any changes made on the target object does not fire notification.

In contrast, the typical way listed below is working.

```
class myArrayController: NSArrayController {
  required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: coder)

    addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "content", options: .new, context: nil)
  }

  override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
    if keyPath == "content" {
      print("Observed a change to \((object as! myArrayController).content.debugDescription)")
    }
    else {
      super.observeValue(forKeyPath: keyPath, of: object, change: change, context: context)
    }
  }
}
```

The new way looks more elegant. Any your suggestions?

Environment: Xcode 9 Beta

- macOS, Cocoa App, Swift 4
- Create Document-Based Application
- Use Core Data
- `myArrayController`'s Mode is **Entity Name**, prepared with `Document.xcdatamodeld`
- `myArrayController`'s **Managed Object Context** is bound to **Model Key Path**: `representedObject.managedObjectContext`
- `representedObject` is assigned with the instance of `Document`.
- `NSTableView`'s **Content**, **Selection Indexes**, and **Sort Descriptors** are bound to the correspondences of the `myArrayController`.

More information on the environment:
**Binding managedObjectContext, Xcode 8.3.2, Storyboards, mac**:
https://forums.bignerdranch.com/t/binding-managedobjectcontext-xcode-8-3-2-storyboards-macos-swift/12284

**EDITED**:

Regarding the example case cited above, I have changed my mind to observe `managedObjectContext`, instead of `content` of `NSArrayController`.

```
class myViewController: NSViewController {

  override func viewWillAppear() {
    super.viewWillAppear()

    let n = NotificationCenter.default
    n.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(mocDidChange(notification:)),
                  name: NSNotification.Name.NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChange,
                  object: (representedObject as! Document).managedObjectContext)
    }
  }

  @objc func mocDidChange(notification n: Notification) {
    print("\nmocDidChange():\n\(n)")
  }

}
```

The reason is that this second approach is simpler than the first one. This code covers all of the desired requirements: additions and deletions of table rows, and modifications of table cells' value. The drawback is that every another table's modification and every yet another entities' modification within the App will cause notifications. Such a notification is not interesting, though. However, that is not a big deal.

In contrast, the first approach will require more complexity.

For additions and deletions, we would need either observing `content` of `NSArrayController` or implementing two functions

```
func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, didAdd rowView: NSTableRowView, forRow row: Int)
func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, didRemove rowView: NSTableRowView, forRow row: Int)
```

from `NSTableViewDelegate`. `NSTableView`'s `delegate` is connected to `NSViewController`.

Slightly surprisingly, the both `tableView()` functions will be called so frequently. For instance, in the situation where there are ten rows in a table, sorting rows will result in ten `didRemove` calls followed by ten `didAdd` calls; adding one row will result in ten `didRemove` calls and then eleven `didAdd` calls. That is not so efficient.

For modifications, we would need

```
func control(_ control: NSControl, textShouldEndEditing fieldEditor: NSText) -> Bool
```

from `NSControlTextEditingDelegate`, a super of `NSTableViewDelegate`. Every `NSTextField` of each table column should be connected to `NSViewController` via its `delegate`.

Furthermore, unfortunately, this `control()` is called right after text edition is completed, but rather, before the actual value in the `NSArrayController` has been updated. That is, somewhat, useless. I have not yet found good solution with the first approach.

**ANYWAY**, the primary topic in this post is how to use **Smart KeyPaths**. :-)

**EDITED 2**:

I am going to use both

1. observing a property `content` of `NSArrayController` ... the first one
2. observing a `Notification` being posted by `NSManagedObjectContext` ... the second one

The 1 is for when a user changes master-details view, which does not make a change on `NSManagedObjectContext`.

The 2 is for when a user makes a change on it: addition, removal, updating, as well as undo, **Command-Z**, which is not accompanied by mouse events.

For now, the version of `addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "content", ...` will be used. Once the question of this post has been solved, I will switch to the version of `observe(\.content, ...`

Thanks.

**EDITED 3**:

The code 2. observing a `Notification` has been completely replaced with new one.

- [How to notice changes on Managed Object Entity handled by Core Data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44866967/how-to-notice-changes-on-managed-object-entity-handled-by-core-data)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

As for your initial code, here's what it should look like:

```
class myArrayController: NSArrayController {
    private var mySub: Any? = nil

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)

        self.mySub = self.observe(\.content, options: [.new]) { object, change in
            debugPrint("Observed a change to", object.content)
        }
    }
}
```

The `observe(...)` function returns a transient observer whose lifetime indicates how long you'll receive notifications for. If the returned observer is `deinit`'d, you will no longer receive notifications. In your case, you never retained the object so it died right after the method scope.

In addition, to manually stop observing, just set `mySub` to `nil`, which implicitly `deinit`s the old observer object.

Comment: Aditya, thank you so much! Your answer perfectly has solved my question. This is a good experience for me coming from the outer, ancient world where there is no ARC. Thanks again!

Comment: Welcome! No worries.

Comment: For those looking for more info, this nice [WWDC 2017 session](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/212/?time=1214) provides further details about *key path observation*.

Comment: Tried this, does not work. What works perfectly fine compile time, run time crashes. `Thread 1: Fatal error: Could not extract a String from KeyPath Swift.ReferenceWritableKeyPath<myapp.Myclass, myapp.Myclass.Myproperty>`

Comment: Also good to add an "invalidate" on the observer in the deinit of the containing class.

Comment: @Yasper: what's good about that? Seems like useless boilerplate code; destruction will deinit the observation anyway.

Comment: @Jonny: late reply, but it's because your keypath property must be `@objc`.

Comment: @Andrey Tarantsov: it is unnecessary, so you're correct. The observer is automatically invalidated on deinitialization.

Comment: @AndreyTarantsov Ah, you're right. The cleanup will happen automatically.