# How to notice changes on Managed Object Entity handled by Core Data?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, notifications, swift4

Motivation is to get a trigger for recalculation upon changes on values of Entity.

My quick solution cited below works, but it has drawbacks. It is inefficient.

In actual App, there are tens of entities. Changes on any of them will cause unnecessary notifications. Those could be avoided, if possible.

In this example, the only EmployeeMO is interested. No other entity needs to be observed.

What is your thoughts?

```
let n = NotificationCenter.default
n.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(mocDidChange(notification:)),
              name: NSNotification.Name.NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChange,
              object: managedObjectContext)

@objc func mocDidChange(notification n: Notification) {
  if n.isRelatedTo(as: EmployeeMO.self) {
    // do recalculation
  }
}
```

And an extension to check if the notification is related to a given managed object:

```
extension Notification {

  public func isRelatedTo<T>(as t: T.Type) -> Bool where T: NSManagedObject {

    typealias S = Set<T>

    let d = userInfo as! [String : Any]

    return d[NSInsertedObjectsKey] is S ||
      d[NSUpdatedObjectsKey] is S ||
      d[NSDeletedObjectsKey] is S ||
      d[NSRefreshedObjectsKey] is S ||
      d[NSInvalidatedObjectsKey] is S
  }

}
```

Xcode 9 Beta, Swift 4

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The is a built in object that does exactly this already -  `NSFetchedResultsController`.  It is designed to work with a tableview or collectionView, but can work fine without one.  It is lightweight enough that it is safe to use for just one object.

Comment: I can't seem to assign a NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate to just a regular class, am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @jon, now my source code has been greatly improved.

```
class myBaseArrayController: NSArrayController, NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate {

  // https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsfetchedresultscontroller
  var frc: NSFetchedResultsController<NSManagedObject>?

  func setupObserver() {
    frc = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: defaultFetchRequest() as! NSFetchRequest<NSManagedObject>,
                                     managedObjectContext: managedObjectContext!,
                                     sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)
    frc?.delegate = self

    do {
      try frc?.performFetch()
    }
    catch {
      fatalError("...")
    }
  }

}
```

Every ArrayController for its corresponding entity simply implements `controllerDidChangeContent()`.

```
class myOneOfThemArrayController: myBaseArrayController {

  func controllerDidChangeContent(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>) {
    print("controllerDidChangeContent: \(controller.fetchRequest.entityName)")
    // do some work
  }

}
```

No more comparison to find which is what for. :-)